# Angular 2 - Change nested form input value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nested-forms

I made a filter for my nested inputs, im using javascript to filter a link whenever paste event is fired.

```
function fixLink(foo){

            if (foo.includes('youtube') && (foo.includes('watch')) || foo.includes('vimeo') && !foo.includes('video') ) {
              foo = foo.includes('youtube') ? 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + foo.slice(foo.indexOf('=') + 1) : foo;
              foo = foo.includes('vimeo') ? 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + foo.slice(foo.indexOf('com/') + 4) : foo;
            }

            return foo;
          }

input.addEventListener('paste', () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              input.text = fixLink(input.value);
              input.value = fixLink(input.value);
            }, 100)
          });
```

This is my HTML

```
@Component({
        selector: 'video-control',
        template: `<div class="form-group p-0 mb-2" [formGroup]="video">
        <div class="input-group group-social">
        <input [disabled]="onHold" class="form-control" formControlName="url" type="text" (focus)="setUrl($event.target)" placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWfWqDhx65s">
        <button type="button" class="remove-photo-gallery btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="removed.emit(index)">
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
        </div>
        </div>`,
      })
```

It changes input value but when i save the value it comes as if the filter didn't work.

I can only get my filter to work if i add something else to the input like a space.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: You should add more information to your question. We don't know what "ng text value" you are referring to as there is no added HTML. You mention "nested inputs" but what nested inputs are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can deduce from your HTML is that you have a `FormGroup` called `video` and it has a `FormControl` called `url`. These are the edits I think you need to make.

Update your input element to use the Angular `(paste)` event emitter:

```
<input [disabled]="onHold" class="form-control" formControlName="url" type="text" (focus)="setUrl($event.target)" (paste)="onPaste($event)" placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWfWqDhx65s">
```

Then in your component have the following method:

```
onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    const clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const fixedLink = this.fixLink(clipboardData.getData('text'));
    window.setTimout(() => this.video.get('url').value = fixedLink);
}
```

You would also need to move this `fixLink` function to be part of the component as well.
If your hope is to have plain JS update the Angular FormGroup then you're using Angular wrong and I strongly advise against continuing along that path.

Comment: i see, where would you recommend me read a little about angular 2? Im really new to angular so i guess im doing stuff really wrong.

Comment: If you haven't already done the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial made by the Angular team then that should absolutely be the first thing you do. It introduces you to a *wide* variety of concepts. Other than that, I personally used PluralSight and whatever random Internet tutorials looked interesting. Of course, nothing beats practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two-way binding to the value of the input element and trigger fixLink function on the paste event to change the property that is bound to the input value.